# how to set up airship in swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I want to try to import airship into my project, but according to the official website settings, I still cannot receive push notifications.

I follew https://docs.airship.com/platform/ios/getting-started/

add
UAirship.takeOff(config)   UAirship.push()?.userPushNotificationsEnabled = true

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BegkH.png.)
in my AppDelegate

and AirshipConfig.plist
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKiYG.jpg)

I use my bundle id in airship demo code can recive push notification, but When I switch to my app test, I can’t receive it

I would like to ask someone who knows that there is a problem with my settings. Thank you！！